# Why does SimpleDateFormat always return the same time?

Tags: java, android

I have a very strange bug. So I have this function:

```
    public static String convertTimeString(long mills) {
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return s.format(new Date(mills));
}
```

I do not understand why the return is the same for this two cases:

```
DateUtils.convertTimeString(epgEvent.getStart())
DateUtils.convertTimeString(epgEvent.getStart() + (timeshift*3600))
```

I noticed that if I add a really big number like > 1000000 the results are not the same, but if I add a few hours the results are the same, which just does not make any sense.

Comment: because the time is in milli seconds, if this makes difference. 1000000 millis will only be 16 minutes.

Comment: you need to show more of the code, we don't even know what timeshift values you are using. 3600 suggests that you plan to use hours (60 mins * 60 seconds) but remember that 1 second is 1000milliseconds so you probably wanted 3600000 in your magic value

Comment: Yes I was adding sec. Thx.

Comment: I am used to theTimeFormat in swift, which is a double and the milliseconds come after the "." so I made this stupid mistake.

Comment: You should work with newer data types for example with `LocalDateTime`. They provide helper methods to increase and decrease certain values like, days, hours, minutes, seconds etc. Easier to handle.